# jQuery simpler way to detach and re attach element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry I could not come up with a better title. I am curious to know what the better, simpler, shorter way to write below function. Specially moving the elements around.

It basically for each `img` creates a parent `div` and places the `img` in there. It also adds `img`'s title attribute in another `div` inside above container.

```
$('.view-sidebar .field-item img').each(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="img-container"></div>');
        $(this).appendTo($(this).parent().find('.img-container'));
        $(this).parent().append('<div class="img-caption">'+$(this).attr('alt')+'</div>');
});
```

Comment: Perhaps you could create a small fiddle to demonstrate what your code does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should just use **[`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)**, there wont be need to append/detach/attach in this case.

```
$(this).wrap('<div class="img-container"></div>');
```

---

```
$('.view-sidebar .field-item img').each(function () {
    var div = $('<div/>', {
        class: 'img-caption',
        text: this.alt
    });
    $(this).wrap('<div class="img-container"></div>').after(div);
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCeU6/4/)**